# C++ Hide template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I don't know if this is possible at all, but I would like to "hide" some template parameters from a given class. Here's what I mean, say I have the following code:

```
template<class A, int b>
class Foo
{
};
template<template<class,int> class Foo_specialized, class A, int b>
class Bar
{
    Foo_specialized<A,b> obj;
};
```

Now supposed Bar does not need to know about A, but needs to know about b.
Naturally something like this would be perfect (the following is a pseudo code just to illustrate the idea):

```
template<template<int> class Foo_specialized_by_first_parameter, int b>
class Bar
{
    Foo_specialized_by_first_parameter<b> obj;
};
```

I'm not really sure if that's possible at all, the idea would be to have something like this when instancing Bar:

```
Bar<Foo<float>, 5> bar_instance;
```

Of course this does not work because Foo doesn't accept 1 parameter.
Basically I need something like `(Foo<float>)<5>` to be possible. The closest thing I can think of is currying in haskell.

Comment: Why not simply `Bar<Foo, 5, float>`, where `template<template <class...>Foo, int ARG, class... FOO_ARGS> struct Bar { Foo<FOO_ARGS..., ARG> obj;};`

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a template-level lambda (or at least template-level partial application).

Comment: @melpomene yeah I guess that's pretty close as an idea. I don't believe it's available in C++ though, is it?

Comment: @lightxbulb, MPL has them. You can do them yourself as well. But that would be complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use template typedef:

```
template <int N>
using Foo_float = Foo<float, N>;
```

And then, with

```
template <template<int> class Foo_specialized_by_first_parameter, int b>
class Bar
{
    Foo_specialized_by_first_parameter<b> obj;
};
```

you may do:

```
Bar<Foo_float, 5> bar_instance;
```

Comment: Kind of reminds me of partial template specialization.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for a second that you can change that int to `std::integral_constant`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template<template<typename...> typename T, typename H>
struct Bind1st
{
    template<typename... Arg>
    using type = T<H, Arg...>;
};

int main() {
    // to bind it
    Bind1st< std::map, std::string >::type< std::string > mymap;
    mymap[ "a" ] = "b";
}
```

Naturally, `Bar< Bind1st< Foo, float >::type, 5 >` should also work.